# Javascript - Sustituir caracteres de texto automáticamente

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo la siguiente pregunta:

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer en `JavaScript` para que si un usuario introduce en un input de texto `HTML` un nombre y un apellido, me devuelva un `String` de texto en el que sea reconocido y sustituido cada espacio en el texto introducido en el input por un símbolo `+`.

Ejemplo: el usuario introduce en el input de texto `HTML` lo siguiente:

```
Juan Pérez Rodríguez
```

`JavaScript` me devuelve un `String` de texto que sea:

```
Juan+Pérez+Rodríguez
```

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cuándo quieres que javascript te genere algo así? cuando sale el focus del input? cuando envía el formulario?

Comment: tengo pensado ponerle al input de texto un onkeyup="funcionx()", siendo la "funcionx()" una funcion que le asigne a una variable nueva como valor una string de texto en la que sean sustituidos dichos espacios por símbolos "+". El problema es que no sé como decirle a javascript que cambie cada espacio por un símbolo "+" como en el ejemplo de arriba. Tendría que dividir el texto en caracteres y exportarlos como array, y que si en un sitio el valor es igual a " ", lo cambie por "+" o como lo soluciono?

Comment: Pero quieres que el String con los "+" añadidos sea sustituído en el input a la vista? O sea que mientras vayas escribiendo el valor del input si el usuario pone un espacio te lo sustituya en ese momento por una "+"?

Comment: No, que le asigne una string de texto como valor a una variable en segundo plano con esos cambios y se la pongo esa funcion al input text como onkeyup.

Comment: @psy ¿Qué haz intentando hasta el momento?

Comment: Aún nada porque necesito ayuda al plantearlo programáticamente. Mi idea era fraccionar a lo mejor cada caracter introducido en el text input a modo de array en segundo plano -> ["e","j","e","m","p","l","o"];      pero eso tendria que ser de alguna forma automática. Luego que cuente la longitud del array, y que compruebe con un if statement si cada instancia de la longitud del array es igual a "(espacio)". Si lo es, se sustituye por "+". No sé si funcionaría algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que desgastarte creando un `array`, con un simple `replace` puedes lograr lo que quieres, prueba con lo siguiente, gatillamos nuestra función `replaceName()` con el evento `onkeyup`. Al valor del `input` le asignamos el mismo valor reemplazando todos (`/ /g`) los espacios en blanco con un ( **+** )

```js
function replaceName(e){
  e.value = e.value.replace(/ /g, "+")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="Ingrese un nombre" 
       id="name"
       onkeyup="replaceName(this)" />
```

Comment: No conocía el replace(), con eso ya me apaño. Es una opción muy sencilla, muchísimas gracias! :)

Comment: @psy Con gusto y para eso estamos, compartir nuestros conocimientos!